# Drive emulation at driver level

Tags: drivers, devices, scsi, sata

I would like to emulate a virtual SED at driver level. The goal is to develop/simulate the "firmware" of a drive, and map driver interface commands to an app which would handle interface specific commands. The driver interface may be one of SCSI, ATA, NVME.

Any hint how to create such an ATA/SCSI/... device, and how to map accesses to a userland app (such as nbd, but at device interface level)?

Comment: The source code of SATA kernel driver sounds like the natural starting point. That's where I would look.